# How can I delete multiple rows in a DataGridView using a CheckBox?

Tags: c#, datagridview, delete-row

How can I delete multiple rows in a `DataGridView` using a `CheckBox`?

I could not find where I do mistakes, but the code throws an error which explains not defined the parameters.

```
DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
SqlCommand delcommand = new SqlCommand();

for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    row = dataGridView1.Rows[i];

    if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[10].Value) == true)
    {
        int id = Convert.ToInt16(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex].Cells[0].Value);

        delcommand.Connection = connection;

        delcommand.CommandText = "DELETE FROM TFirmaBilgileri WHERE id = '" +
        dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "'";

        delcommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        delcommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGridView1.SelectedCells[i].RowIndex);

        i--;
    }
}

connection.close();
```

Comment: Which error and where *code give*?

Comment: Please post your error.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are parsing Id but then not using it. My guess it should be like this.

```
int id = Convert.ToInt16(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex].Cells[0].Value);
delcommand.Connection = connection;
delcommand.CommandText = string.Format("DELETE FROM TFirmaBilgileri WHERE id = {0}",id);
```

Another thing you are not opening connection.

it should be something like

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    var command = connection.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = "...";
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're surrounding the id in single quotes, which most likely is incorrect:

```
delcommand.CommandText = "DELETE FROM TFirmaBilgileri WHERE id = '" +
    dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "'";
```

Parameterize your query to avoid errors like these:

```
int id = Convert.ToInt16(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex].Cells[0].Value);

delcommand.CommandText = "DELETE FROM TFirmaBilgileri WHERE id = @id";
delcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
```

Make sure you're opening your connection too. I don't see that in your code.

I'd also suggest enclosing your `SqlCommand` in a `using` block so that it's disposed properly.